# Transfering calendar events and the events.list sync behavior

Tags: google-calendar-api

If an event is transferred between two calendars (different users) would this show up in the calendar event sync? If so how would it appear?

Worth considering if this shows up either when the transfer request is made, versus when it is accepted by the destination calendar.

Comment: What do you mean with transferred event between two calendars? Could you explain that? Wouldn't this be a simple test with the api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested this today via the API.

After the transfer is accepted, the activity will show in the synced calls from the outgoing organizer. The will no longer have the `organizer.self` attribute which should be an indication that a transfer has happened.